# Grails CAS and REST setup

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security, cas

I have just started with Grails and I am still trying to get my head around it.
In my system I have two types of controllers, usual and rest controllers. 
If ananymous user lands on an action in a usual controller, I want that user to be redirected to a CAS service where he will authenticate. CAS should then redirect back in to my system with a ticket. Given the ticket I have to ask that very same service to give me authenticated entity's identificator (SSN). Having the SSN I have to ask other service to give me groups that would define that user's permissions. Then I have to check in to a third service to get all additional information about the user and create a user entry in my database. Having done all that and having that the whole process went smoothly, then user's workflow should continue. 
If a request is done against the rest controller's action then a 403 headered json formatted error should be returned. 
The whole thing is stateless. Auth token should remain in headers and token is stored in client side.
I consider that quite a custom solution to user authentication and this is that kind of situation when I don't like automagic, alas here I am.

So where I am now. I have added 3 plugins to my grails app:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
compile ":spring-security-cas:2.0-RC1"
compile ":spring-security-rest:1.4.1"
```

And I have setup following config (domain names obscured):

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'package.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'package.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'package.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = '/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = 'https://example.com'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyCallbackUrl = '${grails.serverURL}/secure/receptor'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl ="/j_spring_cas_security_check"
```

But I am pretty sure that I am missing some bits an peaces here and there. 
What does it do right now? Right now unauthorized user is redirected to /auth/login and usual spring security login form greets me there to authenticate. I wish I could turn that behaviour off.

First of all I would like to ask, how could I get spring security to redirect me to CAS for authentication instead of usual one.

Secondly, I would like to ask how to approach the problem where I can implement Custom behaviour for authentication process.

Thirdly, Could anyone in 2 sentences explain what exactly are filters and context of spring security? Maybe there is some article that explains in depth how the whole process works.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have also found an article: http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2010/01/15/hacking-custom-authentication-providers-with-grails-spring-security.html

I wonder IF this is something that can help me and is valid way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for the first question. 
There is a bug reported and discussed: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCAS-4#issue-tabs
Long story short, One has to copy all default config params from cas plugin params. This causes cas plugin to initialize properly.

I will keep looking on a fix/explanation for the other two.

Comment: Would have been great if that link still worked, or if there was a summary of it